# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IContainer'

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I'm trying to add this to my tic tac toe game so in a disablebuttons class

```
foreach (Component c in components)
```

but It gives me an error saying "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IContainer' because 'IContainer' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I'm a beginner so I am sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: `components` isn't a "collection" of things therefore you can't loop over it. If it's an [`IContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icontainer?view=netframework-4.7.2) then you likely want to use [`components.Components`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.icontainer.components?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I with some class name generally means a interface class. And interfaces classes are mostly abstraction classes for inheritance purposes. So look at what is your actual class and cast it to that or use components.Components as @DavidG said